# Remove the bar at the top of the IntelliJ editor showing current scope

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to get rid of some cruft in IntelliJ. How do I hide this bar at the top of the editor? It shows the function/class scope under the cursor:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out: Preferences >> Editor >> General >> Appearance >> (Uncheck) Show Breadcrumbs